# Generate automatically web service parameters

Tags: informatica

I have a scenario where I have to pull data from web service using REST web service consumer transformation. For example the endpoint url is `http://example/2015/Q1`. Here I have to parameterise `2015/Q1` as `$$DATES`. But I cannot change parameter values manually. I have to design my mapping in a way that it should dynamically keep increasing the dates without doing it manually in all the runs including past to future. Please suggest me a way for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a parent workflow which will dynamically create a script with  "pmcmd startworkflow" calls for all the quarters you need. Parent workflow will call the script to invoke the child workflow n number of times. You also need to have a table or file with all the quarters and a flag which will say if that quarter is processed or not. In the child workflow(actual one that you already have) you need to update the flag and mark it as processed. Each run of the child workflow will pick up the first unprocessed quarter and process it.

Hope that helps.